Where is the Auto Smooth Option in Blender 4.1+?
I can't see the Auto Smooth option when I have a mesh selected in Blender 4.1.
Where is it now? How can I find it?
done

Two things: first of all, you could usually do it by right-clicking in the viewport, but therefore you have to be in Object Mode, not Edit Mode. The other thing is, the Auto Smooth function does not exist anymore. But before I simply say, "click on Shade Smooth by Angle instead, you should better watch this video on Youtube which (almost) fully explains the changes and how they affect your work: 4.1 Important change to AutoSmoothing

Auto Smooth is now a modifier: Modifiers > Normals > Smooth by Angles

For versions of Blender 4.1+ the Auto Smooth option under Object data > Normals has been removed as stated in the 4.1 Release Notes.

It has been replaced by a new Geometry Nodes based modifier, than you can add from the modifier list with equivalent functionality.
It can be found under the Modifiers tab, Add Modifier > Normals > Smooth by Angle.

In Edit Mode, you can also use the new Set Sharpness by Angle operator as implemented here https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/pulls/117918
Reasons for removal were several usability issues, including the fact that the UI exposed it as an object data property, but in reality the checkbox was misleading because it was in fact an operation that could unexpectedly get undone at any point by other user actions.
You can read more about it at the relevant task.
